# Does ehcache run in the same process as the servlet container?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ehcache

If I have a spring application that uses ehcache, will ehcache run in the same process and share the same memory as my servlet container?

I know memcache runs in its own process, and was wondering if ehcache can be setup to run in the same memory space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will, unless you use clustering.

Comment: Even with clustering, the cache is still in-process. But there are two levels of caching: The in-process one that, if it can, will hold all the node's hot set; and the terracotta server will be the 2nd level of caching, which holds the entire cached set.

Answer (score 3):

ehcache supports both in-process and out-of process operation. It depends how you set it up.